# show process name and pid in Debian

Tags: c, linux, process, kernel, pid

How can i get and show name and PID for current proccess in a Linux kernel module?
My code  :

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Afiseaza PID si numele executabilului");
MODULE_AUTHOR("ololo");
MODULE_LICENSE("FREE");


static int print_on_init(void)
{
    struct task *cur_task;
    cur_task = get_current();
    printk(KERN_DEBUG, "Hello!\n");
    return 0;
}

static int print_on_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_DEBUG, "Goodbye!\n");
}

module_init(my_hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

Comment: Can you please include the real code instead of a screenshot?? Also, what do you mean by process name? The command line?

Comment: Looks like a Linux kernel question to me, not strictly Debian specific. By the way, why the code as an image?

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert in kernel programming, but you can have a look at how the current PID is retrieved for example in the [code for `exec()`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.3/fs/exec.c#L1384). There seems to be a structure called `current` through which you can extract the data you need. When you click on the variable name in the linked kernel source browser, you get a list of other places this variable is used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [getpid()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getpid) call

Comment: You can't use `getpid()` since it's a function from the standard library, and as such, it is not accessible in a kernel module.